# Run code as per schedule or condition

Tags: java, timertask

I have a requirement where I have to read data from a queue in real-time. The data is to be read using an iterator and I will also maintain a count of the data read from the queue. I will be writing the data to a file.

**EndProcess** : I will be renaming this file with a timestamp and then move it to another place on two conditions (whichever comes first).

1. When the read count has reached 500 and the timer is not completed.
2. When the read count is less than 500 but a particular time (in minutes) has elapsed

**Scenarios:**

- When (1) is first met, I reset the read count and run the EndProcess,
  reset the timer and then will start reading from the queue again.
- When (2) is first met, I will stop reading from the queue, run the
  EndProcess, reset time timer and then resume polling the queue for
  messages.

This is how my code looks like now:

```
while (dataSourceIterator.hasNext()) {
            while (recordCount < recordsPerFile) {
                try {
                    inputPayload = dataSourceIterator.next();
                    if (inputPayload != null) {
                        log.info("Payload ::" + inputPayload.toString());
                        fileTarget.load(inputPayload);
                        fileTarget.commit();
                        recordCount++;
                    } else {
                        log.info("Input Payload is null.");
                    }
                } catch (DataTargetException dataTargetException) {
                    throw new AbortException("Aborting" + dataTargetException.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    throw new AbortException("Aborting " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            }
            recordCount = 0;
            renameFile();
            moveFile();
}
```

Now I have decided to use a `TimerTask` to achieve the timing functionality. But it looks like `TimerTask` does not have an option to reset the timer, I can only cancel it.

Please help me with handling the second scenario. Also, the main reason for using the timer task is to not wait for 500 messages if there are only fewer messages in the queue. That is why we need to have a timer.

Also the scenario where the timer is completed before the 500 messages are read into the file should not happen. The read count takes more precedence than the timer.

**EDIT:** Even when `dataSourceIterator.hasNext()` becomes false, this code will keep running until there is a message in the queue. So it is more like hasNext() will work as if it is always true.

**EDIT 2:** So I think TimerTasks are the way to go. So below is the solution I have now :

```
    MyTimer task = new MyTimer("Timer");

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);

    int processed = 0;
    int recordsPerFile = 5;
    while (true) {
        while (processed < recordsPerFile) {
            System.out.println("processing " + processed);
            if (processed == 3) {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }

            processed++;
        }
        processed = 0;
        task.setTaskStartedBy("CODE");
        task.run();
        task.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        task = new MyTimer("Timer");
        timer.schedule(task, 10000, 5000);
    }

---------------------------

class MyTimer extends TimerTask {

    public String taskStartedBy;

    public MyTimer(String taskStartedBy) {
        this.taskStartedBy = taskStartedBy;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("~End Process~ -- Started by " + taskStartedBy);
    }

    public String getTaskStartedBy() {
        return taskStartedBy;
    }

    public void setTaskStartedBy(String taskStartedBy) {
        this.taskStartedBy = taskStartedBy;
    }

}
```

Here, I have simulated a wait of 15s to notify the code that the messages are fixed. I can see that the timer started by `TIMER` runs. And if that 15s is removed, I can see that the timer started by `CODE` is run.

Please tell me if this approach is right and will work in a production environment. Please also let me know if there is any other better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

A Timer resets itself when a schedule is run. So for example, if you want a task to run every 10 minutes, you just have to schedule one for every 10 minutes. You dont have to reset it to zero after every run. That's automatic.

```
Timer t = new Timer("Read Data");
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourTaskObject,
                       Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
                       60000); //runs once in 10 minutes
```

Comment: But if I set it like that, then the timer will run at the 20th minute even if the record count of 500 is reached or not.

Comment: You should your reading logic inside the Timer Task. It cannot be separate. If the count has not reached 500, just dont do anything.

Comment: I do not want my application to stall if it has already processed 500 records. Is there any way to do that ? Can I manually trigger the schedule method. Or is it right to call the `run` method of my TimeTask class directly which will have the code for the `EndProcess` ?